# I am not able to run my scala program getting Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, class

I am not able to run my scala program getting Error:

> Could not find or load main class.

I have imported my project from Maven.Can any one help me to ressolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: package mainclass****

object MyTest {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf= new SparkConf().setAppName("Experiment").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "1000")
      .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
    val sc= new SparkContext(sc)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val data= spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","\u001C").load("C:/Users/bandaru/Desktop/File.csv").select("Columns")
      .repartition(10, col("request_id"))
  }
}

Comment: Add your code in the question itself. For adding a code block simply press ctrl+k and paste your code there.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean`, `mvn compile`?

Comment: Spark application not use `spark-submit` to run?